# Create label switch

Tags: javascript, html, ionic-framework

I have 5 different labels. I need to click on each one to trigger a function that receives the label text as a parameter. I have something like this:

```
    <div class="fd__fund-performance-chart-card__period">
      <ion-text
        class="ux-font-lato ux-fweight-semibold ux-fsize-14"
        color="uxsemidark"
      >
        24 horas
      </ion-text>
    </div>
    <div class="fd__fund-performance-chart-card__period">
      <ion-text
        class="ux-font-lato ux-fweight-semibold ux-fsize-14"
        color="uxsemidark"
      >
        7 días
      </ion-text>
    </div>
    <div class="fd__fund-performance-chart-card__period">
      <ion-text
        class="ux-font-lato ux-fweight-semibold ux-fsize-14"
        color="uxsemidark"
      >
        30 días
      </ion-text>
    </div>
    <div class="fd__fund-performance-chart-card__period">
      <ion-text
        class="ux-font-lato ux-fweight-semibold ux-fsize-14"
        color="uxsemidark"
      >
        90 días
      </ion-text>
    </div>
    <div class="fd__fund-performance-chart-card__period">
      <ion-text
        class="ux-font-lato ux-fweight-semibold ux-fsize-14"
        color="uxsemidark"
      >
        Todo
      </ion-text>
    </div>
```

And the function is simple:

```
function imprimir(label) {
  alert(label)
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: Hello! Is this question related to Ionic or the `ionic-framework` tag has been added by mistake? Btw, saludos de otro argentino! :)